# Cast (void *) to any other in a safe way

Tags: c++, c, curl

Is this safe now?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

long lee( void *v1)
{
     long i1;
     memcpy(&i1,v1,sizeof(long));
     return i1;
}

//Added conversion to double:
double lee_d( void *v1)
{
     double i1;
     memcpy(&i1,v1,sizeof(double));
     return i1;
}

void main()
{
     long val=1777777;

     long ii;
     ii=lee((void *) &val);

     double dd=377e-177;
     dd=lee_d((void *) &dd);
     ii=ii;
}
```

It works well under MS studio.

I do not use this pointer translations but when using curl libraries

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code O.O And what is your definition for "safe code"?

Comment: it's a `void*`, there is nothing *safe* about it...

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: You don't need to cast to `void*`, so don't do it. In fact, if you boil this program down to its essentials, you end up with something like `int main() { return 0; }`.

Comment: You are right. But I have use that conversions with Curls functions that passes (void *) parameters

Answer (score 2):

The integral division will happen before the adding of 0.99999 therefore you are going to get an integer, which may be 0, 1, 2, add an arbitrary 0.99999 to it which achieves nothing, then cast it back to long.

size1 could still be 0 so `val[0]` might not be valid.

It is also difficult to know what you are trying to achieve.

To answer your question directly, it is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

As far as lee() and your call to it goes, yes it's safe.

Comment: Sorry, I answered before your answer -Pleyades-

Answer (score 0):

As has been said the (void *) are unneccessary & should be avoided until you know what you're doing.  In the function declaration concerned it just means the function takes a pointer to something but it doesn't matter what the type of 'something' is.

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

static void doit(int *);        // Function Prototypes.  VERY IMPORTANT.
static void doitAgain(void *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i = 0x12345;
    doit(&i);
    doitAgain(&i);

}


static void doit(int *b) 
{ 

    int *foo = malloc(sizeof(int));

    memcpy(foo, b, sizeof(int));

    fprintf(stdout, "foo is 0x%x\n", *foo);
}

static void doitAgain(void *b) 
{ 

    int *foo = malloc(sizeof(int));

    memcpy(foo, b, sizeof(int));

    fprintf(stdout, "foo is 0x%x\n", *foo);
}
```

And when we run it:

```
$ make
cc     main.c   -o main
$ ./main 
foo is 0x12345
foo is 0x12345
```

Comment: The thing is that once you "know what you're doing", you will rarely use `void*`. You want to be as specific as possible with types, and `void*` is the least specific possible. The moment you know *anything* about the type, don't use `void*`. In this example, `doItAgain(void*)` makes assumptions about what `b` is (the size, or the knowledge that it can be converted to an `int` bit-for-bit). @David Victor is totally right by saying "doesnt matter what 'something' is". In all the examples given in this question, it *does* matter what 'something' is, thus `void*` should not be used.

Comment: Yes.  The point of the code sample is to show you **don't** need (void *) - it works fine **without** it.  But use it "rarely" if/when you need to....  As the example functions are (now magically) static - I can make some assumptions ... Again I wouldn't do things this way anyway.   Tough crowd ;-)

Comment: [quote]thus void* should not be used[/quote] Then do not use phread lybrary or Curl ones:                                             int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *arg);